# Conversion error int? to string in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have problems trying to left join in a table where the PK and FK has different types.
int? to string, decimal to string and vice-versa

```
public VDB_TABLE1()
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string AnotherValue {get; set;}
   public string FKTable2 {get; set;}
   public string FKTable3 {get; set;}
}

public VDB_TABLE2()
{
   public int? PKTable2 {get; set;}
   public string AnotherValue {get; set;}
}

public VDB_TABLE3()
{
   public decimal PKTable3 {get; set;}
   public string AnotherValue {get; set;}
}
```

That's my ViewModel:

```
public VDB_MYVIEWMODEL()
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string AnotherValue {get; set;}
   public VDB_TABLE2 TABLE2 {get; set;}
   public VDB_TABLE3 TABLE3 {get; set;}
}
```

The query:

```
 var query = (from t1 in context.VDB_TABLE1
                from t2 in context.VDB_TABLE2.Where(t2 => t2.PKTable2 == t1.FKTable2).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from t3 in context.VDB_TABLE3.Where(t3 => t3.PKTable3 == t1.FKTable3).DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new MYVIEWMODEL
 {
   Id = t1.Id,
   AnotherValue = t1.AnotherValue,
   TABLE2 = t2,
   TABLE3 = t3
 }).ToList();
```

Comment: How did you manage to create a foreign key pointing to a different data type? Or is it a "fake" foreign key? If it's the latter, you need to handle the conversion yourself.

Comment: As @Albireo said, FK's should share the data type of the PK it is referencing, otherwise they aren't proper FK's. Would be better to redesign your DB table to conform to the correct practice

Comment: @Albireo That's the problem, I can not modify the database structure for the database client is running and there are already systems in this structure, just have no idea how they are working 'rs

Comment: @Takarii That's the problem, I can not modify the database structure for the database client is running and there are already systems in this structure, just have no idea how they are working 'rs

Comment: in that case, take both values, parse them to strings and compare them using c#. based on outcome, do "stuff"

Comment: @Takarii I tried in every way to make data conversions in this context but none worked, all gave errors.

Comment: so you tried something as simple as `if (val1.ToString() == val2.ToString())` check?

Comment: it might be helpful to know what DBMS you are using too

Comment: @Takarii I tried this, but the entity framework linq does not support this type of conversion

Comment: Why do you need different types on FK and PK? As far as I am concerned, FK correction is the only usage for FK values (in joins), where both have to have the same datatype. if all else fails, you have to do the join in steps and converse in-memory in between.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Change the structure of the database is my last choice, I wonder if it is possible to make some kind of cast through the code just for this query.

Comment: @vtncgustavo changing the structure should be PRIMARY not secondary. Whoever designed it in the first place did so badly and you should correct that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be impossible to get EF to behave this way. MSSQL Server will not even let you make this type of relationship. If you don't mind a little SQL, you can do what you want using LinqToSQL

Modify your view model

```
public VDB_MYVIEWMODEL()
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string AnotherValue {get; set;}
   public string T2 {get; set;}
   public string T3 {get; set;}
}

string sSQL "Select VDB_TABLE1.Id, VDB_TABLE1.AnotherValue, VDB_TABLE2.AnotherValue as T2, VDB_TABLE3.AnotherValue as T3 from VDB_TABLE1 left join VDB_TABLE2 on VDB_TABLE1.FKTable2 = VDB_TABLE2.PKTable2 left join VDB_TABLE3 on VDB_TABLE1.FKTable3 = VDB_TABLE3.PKTable3;";

List<VDB_MYVIEWMODEL> Results = context.Database.SqlQuery<VDB_MYVIEWMODEL>(sSql).ToList();
```

One other option would be to change your model like so.

```
public VDB_TABLE1()
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string AnotherValue {get; set;}
   public string FKTable2 {get; set;}
   public VDB_TABLE2 Table2
   {
     get
     {
       int id = Convert.ToInt32(FKTable2);
       return context.VDB_TABLE2.Find(id);
     }
   }

   ...do similar for Table3
}
```

Query like so, and access the values like:

```
var query = (from t1 in context.VDB_TABLE1);

query.Id
query.AnotherValue
query.Table2.AnotherValue
query.Table3.AnotherValue
```

Warning, this is very inefficient. You are making two extra db calls for every record in your primary table. If you only have a few records...then this might be OK for you.